# How to iterate tree PHP

Tags: php, recursion, tree, iteration

I have a structure like this. The structure has many categories:

```
-Cat 1
   -subCat
-Cat 2
   -subCat
      -subcat
-Cat3
```

How could I print them using iteration and recursion? Also, store them and add and remove items?

Thanks

Comment: At the very least, post the relevant data structures you want to traverse.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Learn PHP and ask a specific question regarding your implementation as soon as it occurs.

Comment: Strictly speaking you don't iterate tree structures, you traverse them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on what kind of tree you are using. Are you talking about a binary tree, binary search tree or a "regular" tree (with multiple children).

For binary search trees you can use binary search:

```
  public function search($value): ?BinarySearchNode {
        /** @var BinarySearchNode $node */
        $node = $this->getRoot();
        while (null !== $node) {
            if (Comparator::equals($value, $node->getValue())) {
                return $node;
            } else if (Comparator::lessThan($value, $node->getValue())) {
                $node = $node->getLeft();
            } else if (Comparator::greaterThan($value, $node->getValue())) {
                $node = $node->getRight();
            } else {
                throw new InvalidSearchComparisionException("no comparision returned true. Maybe you passed different data types (scalar, object)?");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

There is also Tree Traversal: Pre-Order, In-Order and Post-Order-Traversal. The following demonstrates Pre-Order:

```
  public function _traverse(?IBinaryNode $node) {
        if (null !== $node) {
            parent::visit($node->getValue());
            if (null !== $node->getLeft()) {
                $this->_traverse($node->getLeft());
            }
            if (null !== $node->getRight()) {
                $this->_traverse($node->getRight());
            }
        }
    }
```

In general, as trees are graphs, you could use DFS or BFS. The following is example code for BFS:

```
  public function searchByNode(?Node $node) {
        if (null === $node) return;
        $queue = new Queue();
        $this->visited->add($node);
        $queue->enqueue($node);
        while (!$queue->isEmpty()) {
            /** @var Node $n */
            $n = $queue->dequeue();
            $this->visit($n);
            /** @var Node $adjacent */
            foreach ($n->getAdjacents() as $adjacent) {
                if (!$this->visited->containsValue($adjacent)) {
                    $this->visited->add($adjacent);
                    $queue->enqueue($adjacent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: The examples are from a lib, have a look here: https://github.com/doganoo/PHPAlgorithms

Comment: I'd strongly advise against attempting to answer overly broad questions.  The correct approach is to get the asker to narrow down what they're asking to something more answerable.

Comment: I agree. But on the other hand, there are not many ways to iterate over trees. So thats why I just wanted to show 2 samples.